# How can I get the total grades of the google form?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form as an examination, I want to get the maximum score, and the student score to get the percentage , but I couldn't get the maximum and I don't know how to get that

I have tried the following function and it got the respondent score but didn't get the maximum grade of the form:

```
function mayFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();

  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];
    var items = formResponse.getItemResponses();

    var maxiGrade = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      var itemResponseId = formResponse.getItemResponseId(j);
      var itemResponse = form.getItemResponseById(itemResponseId);
      if (itemResponse.isGradable()) {
        maxiGrade += itemResponse.getMaxScore();
      }
    }
  }
  var grade = formResponse.getGradableItemResponses().reduce((p,e) => p +=e.getScore(),0);
  var result = (grade/maxiGrade)*100
  Logger.log(result);
}
```

please help me to get that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your showing script, I believe that you might have wanted the average of each response or the average of total responses.

About `I have tried the following function and it got the respondent score but didn't get the maximum grade of the form:`, when I saw your script, I thought that your script doesn't work because `FormApp.FormResponse` has no method of `getItemResponseId`. And also, unfortunately, `FormApp.Form` has no method of `getItemResponseById`. So, I'm worried that your showing script might be different from your tested script. So, in this case, I would like to propose a sample script.

#### Sample script:

In this script, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Form. And save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const itemObj = {
    "DATE": "asDateItem",
    "LIST": "asListItem",
    "TEXT": "asTextItem",
    "TIME": "asTimeItem",
    "CHECKBOX": "asCheckboxItem",
    "MULTIPLE_CHOICE": "asMultipleChoiceItem",
    "PARAGRAPH_TEXT": "asParagraphTextItem",
    "SCALE": "asScaleItem",
    "DATETIME": "asDateTimeItem",
    "DURATION": "asDurationItem",
  };
  const maxScore = form.getItems().reduce((n, item) => {
    const i = itemObj[item.getType().toString()];
    if (i) {
      n += item[i]().getPoints();
    }
    return n;
  }, 0);
  const averages = form.getResponses().map(r1 => (r1.getGradableItemResponses().reduce((n, r2) => n += r2.getScore(), 0) / maxScore) * 100);
  const average = averages.reduce((n, e) => n += e, 0) / averages.length;

  console.log(averages); // Averages of each response.
  console.log(average); // Average of total responses.
}
```

- When this script is run, the averages of each response and total responses are obtained.

#### References:

- [Class Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form)
- [Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)